# Windows Phone 8.1 LongListSelector with Images

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a long list selector in my application. The list should display an icon and a caption below it. It appears as a grid as seen in the image below

[image]

The icon should be downloaded from the server and displayed, the icon is downloaded from the server as an byte array which can be used to generate the Bitmap. How do i bind the Bitmap to the Image in my LongListSelectors template. My data template is as below.

```
  <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="5,5,5,5" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">
                            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <Image Height="70" Width="70"  Margin="10,0,0,0" Source="/Assets/Images/appimg.png">
                                </Image>
                            </Grid>
                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center">        
                            <TextBlock Margin="5,5,5,5" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding appTitle}"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
 </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
```

Currently in the template the icon path is hardcoded. Please provide some input on how to bind the bitmap to the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Conveter

Assuming the assembly name of the phone project is: PhoneApp1

Create a converter with the following code:

```
using System;

namespace PhoneApp1.Converters
{
   using System.Globalization;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Windows.Data;
   using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

public class ByteToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var data = value as byte[];

        if (data != null)
        {
            using(var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
            {
                var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
                return bitmapImage;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
}
```

use the following namespace declaration in your xaml:

```
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:PhoneApp1.Converters"
```

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <converters:ByteToImageConverter x:Key="ByteToImageConverter" />
        </Grid.Resources>
       <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="lstTiles">
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="5,5,5,5" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">
                        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Image Height="70" Width="70"  Margin="10,0,0,0" Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource ByteToImageConverter}}">
                            </Image>
                        </Grid>
                        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock Margin="5,5,5,5" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
    </Grid>
```

Code Behind and Model

```
 public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindTiles();
    }


    private void BindTiles()
    {
        var sampleRandomImageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(@"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGgAAABbCAYAAACf8sCiAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAADeSURBVHhe7dExAQAwDMCgmVj9O21tcORAAe/PbFwF4QrCFYQrCFcQriBcQbiCcAXhCsIVhCsIVxCuIFxBuIJwBeEKwhWEKwhXEK4gXEG4gnAF4QrCFYQrCFcQriBcQbiCcAXhCsIVhCsIVxCuIFxBuIJwBeEKwhWEKwhXEK4gXEG4gnAF4QrCFYQrCFcQriBcQbiCcAXhCsIVhCsIVxCuIFxBuIJwBeEKwhWEKwhXEK4gXEG4gnAF4QrCFYQrCFcQriBcQbiCcAXhCsIVhCsIVxCuIFxBuIJwBeEKos0e0/44s5MWYKUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=");

        var data = new[]
        {
            new AppTitle { Title = "Tile 1", Image = sampleRandomImageBytes }, new AppTitle { Title = "Tile 2", Image = sampleRandomImageBytes },
            new AppTitle { Title = "Tile 3", Image = sampleRandomImageBytes }, new AppTitle { Title = "Tile 4", Image = sampleRandomImageBytes }
        };

        lstTiles.ItemsSource = data;
    }
}

public class AppTitle
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've included this in my project and added this at the top of my xaml page xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XYZ.Framework" and my grid resource as  <Grid.Resources>
            <local:ByteToImageConverter x:Key="ByteToImageConverter" />
        </Grid.Resources> but when i run the project i get the following error  Message=Cannot create instance of type 'XYZ.Framework.ByteToImageConverter'. Am i missing out something here?

Comment: You are running into namespace issues, I have updated the questions to include my namespace. Substitute PhoneApp1 with your assembly name, to find out what your assembly name is, go to your project in solution explorer, right click, properties and the assembly name should be displayed in the application tab. Might be worth investing in Resharper for c#, saves you a tonne of time handwriting namespaces.

Comment: My bad :-( the ByteToImageConverter class was not public. Hence the error. Thank you for the quick help. Kudos.